# how to add credit card payment option in ccavenue payment gateway

Tags: php, ccavenue

I have implemented non-seamless integration kit php for ccavenue payment gateway. but in checkout page of ccavenue option for payment by credit card is not displaying.thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: i have implemented ccavenue payment gateway in my website. but in ccavenue checkout page it is not showing option to pay with credit card.?

Answer (score 0):

Today I got my credit card activated in my website. Following are the steps

1) To get Indian Credit card activated, Please mail to salessupport@ccavenue.com. They will activate in 30 mins.
 
2) To get international Credit card activated, Please submit Bank Account statement for last one year. Scan copy will work.